# Spark 2.0 GROUP BY NULLS

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5, apache-spark-2.0

Working on migrating some queries from Spark 1.5 to Spark 2.0

The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
    users.age AS users_age,

  NULL

 AS users_running_total_on_null
FROM users

GROUP BY users.age
ORDER BY users_age 
LIMIT 1
```

First of all, I know in Spark, null checks don't work when used in a group by, and calling `LENGTH()` on the value and null checking works correctly.

Running the above query, I get the following error:

`SQL Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized type name: null\"`

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: did it work it 1.5 ?

Comment: Yes, it worked in 1.5

Comment: you have created a data frame and issues this sql command right ?

Comment: can you post code where you have data frame and this query in 1.5

Comment: I believe you wont be able to select null as column

Comment: What's a "data frame"?

Comment: post your code , where is your table ? is it in Hive ? or you are creating Data Frame RDD using a data source ? check this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html